# PYTHON: How do deal with data types after np.fromfile (binary format) correctly?

Tags: python, numpy

I have various problems with my assigned data types after read from any binary file with `np.fromfile` and `np.memmap`.

I am reading the following:

```
openfile = open(mypath,'rb')
openfile.seek(start_byte)
myvalue = np.fromfile(openfile, dtype = np.uint64, count=1)

print myvalue
```

return:

```
myvalue = [1234]
```

`myvalue` has 8 bytes and is interpreted as an ndarray, but I want just an uint64-value using it as an index.

**1) How to prevent np.fromfile to write in an ndarray?**

If I am trying: `myvalue = myvalue[0]` `myvalue` loses it's data type completely.

**2) Why does `myvalue` looses it's data type when I am accessing the first**

I have to do something like that with my arrays:

```
data.extend([myvalue for l in range(myvalue)])
```

Try to assign again a data type: `myvalue = myvalue[0].astype(np.uint64)`. Now I get:

```
self.data_array[count:count+myvalue,0] = data[count:count+myvalue]   
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

**3) What is going wrong here?**

If I am assigning myvalue as: `myvalue = myvalue[0].astype(np.int32)` The data is interpreted wrongly and I get: `-35566848567` etc.

**4) Why can myvalue still be wrongly interpreted by the programme after read in since**
`myvalue = myvalue[0].astype(np.int32)`
**IS NOT**
`myvalue = myvalue[0].astype(np.uint64)`

Comment: As for questions 3) and 4): `int32` only has 4 bytes and your 8 byte value overflows if you convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the possible non-answer, but it's easier to post code this way...

Why do you think that myvalue loses its type information?  It doesn't do that when I try it here (Python 2.7):

```
>>> myvalue = np.array([1234], np.uint64)
>>> myvalue = myvalue[0]
>>> type(myvalue)
<type 'numpy.uint64'>
```

Comment: Thank's for anserwing: aha, it tried `np.info(myvalue)` result: `none`

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning about using `fromfile` in its docs:

> Notes
>   ----- Do not rely on the combination of `tofile` and `fromfile` for data storage, as the binary files generated are are not platform
>   independent.  In particular, no byte-order or data-type information is
>   saved.  Data can be stored in the platform independent `.npy` format
>   using `save` and `load` instead.

Comment: it would be good it if is platform independent, but I am unfortunately stuck with .dat files generated by C routines and I have a lot of trouble with them. What would you recommend me to load binary data? What type of load()? pickle?

Comment: No, not pickle.  You can handle different binary formats with the native Python array module, the native python struct module or even the native Python ctypes module.  Also, binascii is sometimes useful.

Comment: @Patrick I would recommend OP sticks with `numpy.fromfile` *if* the goal is to read a large data set. All approaches are equally bad in the sense that the binary format has to be specified explicitly.